# How to connect to MySql in another Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database-connection

Hi How do i connect to MySql from another Ubuntu machine. I tried  this

```
mysql -h 'IP' -P 3306 -u test -ptest
```

I get ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (111). then i tried

```
 nmap -sS -O -p 3306 'IP'   and it says 3306/tcp closed mysql
```

But in the MySql machine when i try it with localhost it works

```
 nmap -sS -O -p 3306 localhost it says 3306/tcp open mysql
```

What am i missing here

Comment: Is your other machine set up for remote access to mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to check this:

[1] in /etc/mysql/my.cnf if the database is configured to be listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) only.
Look for the line

```
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

and comment this line, follow by a restart of the database.
I think this is your issue, since this is default in Ubuntu.

[2] Run "netstat -an | grep 3306" - it should give this when open for connections from the outside:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: When bind-address was commented it worked. Thanks mate

Comment: By commenting bind-address is mysql secure are there any security issues

Comment: Yes this IS a potential security issue indeed. At least use a firewall to limit access to port 3306. Google for the rest ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You must create an user that's allowed to connect to that MySQL server from the machine you want to connect from.

mysql > create user 'user'@'ip_from_you_want_to_connect' identified by 'password'.

The trick is, in the create user syntax, what you put after the @

create user 'user'@'localhost' only gives permission to that user when connecting from the local machine.

If you want to connect from another machine, replace the localhost with the IP or the name (FQDN) of that machine.

You can find out more about creating users [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

Also, check the hint given by Henk.